# iMac 8,1: where to put thermal sensor after SSD installation

Tags: imac, ssd, repair

I'm installing an SSD in an early 2008 iMac (8,1) which has a thermal sensor taped to the current hard drive.  After reading nearly twenty threads on the subject I'm having difficulty determining what is the best thing to do with the thermal sensor.

These are the suggestions I've seen:

- Short it out.
- Disconnect it and use software to control fan speed.
- Attach it somewhere else inside the unit where there is a bit of heat to prevent the machine from going into protection mode

I'm most attracted to the last option but have yet to see any definitive answer about where exactly it should be positioned in that case.

I would like to know if anyone has a definitive answer about the correct way deal with the thermal sensor when installing an SSD which generates little to no heat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up placing the thermal sensor in the small space directly below the plug where it connects.  There are three sensors in a line which connect here and below them an empty space large enough to hold the sensor and sensor bracket.

After reassembling everything the sensor is functioning and fan speeds are normal.